# Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated with prolog clpfd

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am working with CLPFD and I cannot seem to get rid of the error:

```
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [16] throw(error(instantiation_error,_9234))
ERROR:   [12] clpfd:drep_to_domain(_9270..15,_9266) at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/library/clp/clpfd.pl:3652
ERROR:   [11] clpfd:clpfd_in(_9302,_9308..15) at /usr/lib/swi-prolog/library/clp/clpfd.pl:1608
ERROR:   [10] computeShapeBelow([[circle|...],6|...],[[diamond|...],_9370|...])
```

Below is my program and it is clear to me that Dim1 and Dim2 which come from nth0/3 are causing Prolog to throw this error. How can I work around this? I cannot find a way to apply the solutions I have seen here on StackOverflow with CLPFD

```
    :- use_module(library(clpfd)). 

        computeShapeBelow(Shape1,Shape2) :- 
                                nth0(2,Shape1,Location1),
                                nth0(2,Shape2,Location2),
                                nth0(1,Shape1,Dim1),
                                nth0(1,Shape2,Dim2), 
                                nth0(0,Location1,Xcord1),
                                nth0(0,Location2,Xcord2),                                                 
                                nth0(1,Location1,Ycord1),
                                nth0(1,Location2,Ycord2),
                                XlowerLimit1 #= Dim1, 
                                XupperLimit1 #= 20-Dim1,
                                YlowerLimit1 #= Dim1, 
                                YupperLimit1 #= 15-Dim1,
                                XlowerLimit2 #= Dim2, 
                                XupperLimit2 #= 20-Dim2,
                                YlowerLimit2 #= Dim2, 
                                YupperLimit2 #= 15-Dim2,
                                Ycord1 in YlowerLimit1..YupperLimit1, 
                                Ycord2 in YlowerLimit2..YupperLimit2,
                                Xcord1 in XlowerLimit1..XupperLimit1, 
                                Xcord2 in XlowerLimit2..XupperLimit2,                                     
                                Ycord2 #> Ycord1+Dim2+Dim1,                                               
                                labeling([min(Xcord1),
                                     min(Ycord2),
                                     max(Xcord2),  
                                     max(Ycord2)],
                                    [Xcord1,Ycord1,Xcord2,Ycord2]).
```

**Edit**
`listing(computeShapeBelow)` produces the following.

```
computeShapeBelow(A, B) :-
    nth0(2, A, C),
    nth0(2, B, D),
    nth0(1, A, E),
    nth0(1, B, J),
    nth0(0, C, Q),
    nth0(0, D, R),
    nth0(1, C, O),
    nth0(1, D, P),
    (   integer(E)
    ->  F=E
    ;   clpfd:clpfd_equal(F, E)
    ),
    (   integer(E)
    ->  G is 20-E
    ;   clpfd:clpfd_equal(G, 20-E)
    ),
    (   integer(E)
    ->  H=E
    ;   clpfd:clpfd_equal(H, E)
    ),
    (   integer(E)
    ->  I is 15-E
    ;   clpfd:clpfd_equal(I, 15-E)
    ),
    (   integer(J)
    ->  K=J
    ;   clpfd:clpfd_equal(K, J)
    ),
    (   integer(J)
    ->  L is 20-J
    ;   clpfd:clpfd_equal(L, 20-J)
    ),
    (   integer(J)
    ->  M=J
    ;   clpfd:clpfd_equal(M, J)
    ),
    (   integer(J)
    ->  N is 15-J
    ;   clpfd:clpfd_equal(N, 15-J)
    ),
    clpfd:clpfd_in(O, H..I),
    clpfd:clpfd_in(P, M..N),
    clpfd:clpfd_in(Q, F..G),
    clpfd:clpfd_in(R, K..L),
    (   integer(P)
    ->  (   integer(O),
        integer(J),
        integer(E)
        ->  P>=O+J+E+1
        ;   S=P,
        clpfd:clpfd_geq(S, O+J+E+1)
        )
    ;   integer(O),
        integer(J),
        integer(E)
    ->  S is O+J+E+1,
        clpfd:clpfd_geq(P, S)
    ;   clpfd:clpfd_geq(P, O+J+E+1)
    ).
```

Comment: The error message didn't give you a line number?

Comment: It appears Swi-prolog only highlights the violating predicate. In my case it is line 106 which is the line where computeShapeBelow/2 starts.

Comment: Getting rid of Dim1 and Dim2 of the upper and lower limits solves the error. So it must be nth0/produces partially instantiated variables Dim1 and Dim2. Is there a way to make them fully instantiated or a workaround?

Comment: Please use a better formatting, like that produced by `listing(computeShapeBelow)`

Comment: I have added listing(computeShapeBelow) result

Comment: A variable is either instantiated or it is not. It can't be "partially" instantiated. If `nth0(1,Shape1,Dim1)` results in an unbound `Dim1`, that means that the second element of `Shape1` isn't instantiated.

Comment: propertyMagnitude(ShapesIn,ShapesOut,Subject)--> property, [X],{integer(X),  append(  [[Subject, X, [Xcord,Ycord]]], ShapesIn, ShapesOut)}.              Look at the append in this DCG. That is how I obtain Dim1 and Dim2. 'X' is not instantiated?. It is part of the sentence being parsed. How can I instantiate it?

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Include it in your question via edit as it will be much more readable and others will see it. Also, it's impossible to know what's happening with `X` without knowing what your query was that you entered. Where is `property` defined? The instantiation error is occurring before the `append/3` since `append` doesn't care whether it's instantiated. I suspect `integer(X)` is flagging `X` as uninstantiated, meaning it's uninstantiated on the input DCG stream `[X]`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error is your using **variables as domain boundaries** in `(in)/2`.

As a minimal example that shows the problem, consider:

```
?- Var in X..Y.
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

For `(in)/2`, the domain must be *ground*. It is not admissible to use only partially instantiated domains.

A possible workaround for this concrete issue is using arithmetic constraints like `(#>)/2` etc. instead of `(in)/2`. For example:

```
my_in(Var, Lower, Upper) :-
        Lower #=< Var, Var #=< Upper.
```

If you use this predicate instead of `(in)/2` in your code, your issue disappears. I leave figuring out how to use the predicate as a small challenge.

However, other issues will then surface. I think they should be discussed separately, in a new question.